# How do i run the same function which involves row and column indices over multiple data frames that are in a list?

Tags: r

Game1 is just one dataframe and I applied these functions to it but now I want to be able to do this to each dataframe in a list which I imported using a DataLoader package.

```
Game1$Goal=Goal <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(Game1))
ifelse(Game1$EventName[i] == "Shot" && Game1$EventName[i+1] == "Goal" |     Game1$EventName[i] == "Header Shot" && Game1$EventName[i+1] == "Goal",   Game1$Goal[i] <- 1, Game1$Goal[i] <- 0)

Game1shot <- subset(Game1, EventName == "Shot" | EventName == "Header Shot")

nRowsz <- nrow(Game1shot)
for (i in 1:nrow(Game1){
  Zone1 <- as.integer(Game1$Zone == "Zone 1")
  Zone2 <- as.integer(Game1$Zone == "Zone 2")
  Zone3 <- as.integer(Game1$Zone == "Zone 3")
  ........
  Zone100 <- as.integer(Game1$Zone == "Zone 100")
  Goal <- Game1$Goal

  Gamefinal1 <- data.frame(Zone1,......,Zone100,Goal)
  }
```

and this counties until Zone100 and all these Zone"" vectors are made into a new data frame named "Gamefinal1" for Game1 but i want this for all Games.

After importing all the csv files as dataframes which are elements in a list. 
I tried writing code with these 2 methods so i can apply the functions above to each element in this list but it doesn't working.

Method 1

```
Games <- importCsv(path = "")
Games <- lapply(Games, function(x) {
  for(j in 1:nrow(x))
    ifelse(x$EventName[j] == "Shot" && x$EventName[j+1] == "Goal",   x$Goal[j] <- 1, x$Goal[j] <- 0)
  })
```

Method 2

```
for(i in Games){
      for(j in 1:nrow(i))
      ifelse(i$EventName[j] == "Shot" && i$EventName[j+1] == "Goal" |  i$EventName[j] == "Header Shot" && i$EventName[j+1] == "Goal", i$Goal[j] <-  1, i$Goal[j] <- 0)
      }
```

After running Method 2, it say there are 50 or more warnings.. and they are 
[Warnings from Method 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzHv2.png)

Thanks in advance!!

[Snippet of how the data looks][2]

Simplied version of how the data looks

```
Half        Time     EventName      Rotation   Zone
First Half  0        Start Of Half  180        Zone 46
First Half  0.5      Touch          180        Zone 46
First Half  1.5      Shot           180        Zone 46
First Half  13.1     Throw In       0          Zone 99
First Half  14.8     Header         0          Zone 57
First Half  22.6     Shot           180        Zone 44
First Half  23.6     Goal           180        Zone 44
First Half  25       Touch          0          Zone 99
First Half  26       Shot           0          Zone 97
First Half  27       Pass           0          Zone 90
First Half  27.9     Header Shot    0          Zone 91
First Half  29.3     Goal           0          Zone 54  
First Half  30.6     Pass           0          Zone 54
First Half  33       Touch          0          Zone 59
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Also check that you first code chunk is complete and runs correctly -- you have embedded for loops and both are missing a closing bracket and no i index is referenced in the body of the second loop.

Comment: I would like to see how the *Zones* vectors are rendered into dataframe considering they may have different lengths. Please include that code abbreviating up until 100 as needed.

Comment: @R.S. The first code chunk does work and it did exactly what i needed but that's just for one data frame i imported individually. So I was able to use the name of that data frame, for ex, (Game1$EventName) to specifically call each column that i want the ifelse condition checked for. And for the indexing, are you referring to the Method 2 I tried?

Comment: @Parfait I just added the code i used to render the zones into a new data frame which in this instinct i name Gamefinal1.

Comment: *it doesn't work*...is not helpful. What is the error/undesired result? And what does `importCsv()` return: a list of strings for dataframes names or list of dataframes?

Comment: @Parfait it was there are 50+ warnings and above I linked a image which shows the warnings. And importCsv() returns a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting your `ifelse` to avoid assignment calls within it. Also, consider an `sapply` on a character vector of zones (*"Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", ...*):

```
Zones <- paste("Zone", seq(100))
Games <- importCsv(path = "")

NewGames <- lapply(Games, function(x) {
  for(i in seq(nrow(x)-1)) {
    x$Goal[i] <- ifelse((x$EventName[i] == "Shot" & x$EventName[i+1] == "Goal") |     
                        (x$EventName[i] == "Header Shot" & x$EventName[i+1] == "Goal"), 1, 0)
  }

  subGame <- subset(x, EventName == "Shot" | EventName == "Header Shot")      
  Zones_mat <- sapply(Zones, function(z){
    as.integer(subGame$Zone == z)      
  })

  Zones_mat <- cbind(Zones_mat, subGame$Goal)
  colnames(Zones_mat) <- append(gsub(" ", "", Zones), "Goal")
})
```

[R Fiddle Demo](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=RVKyhyRn&version=2)

Comment: So i tried it with this approach and it was giving me this error,     "In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = structure(c(1L, 1L,  ... :  invalid factor level, NA generated"     Then I imported two csv files with setting stringsAsFactors =F and apply your code then it ran but gave me Null for the new elements of the list.

Comment: Can you post a snippet (few lines of one of your CSV files)? Even better is a dput dump: `dput(mydataframe)`?

Comment: Yup just added a link at the above at the end of question.

Comment: Please insert the data inside your post, no screenshots please as we cannot copy and paste it on our end to run a reproducible example.

Comment: See edit. Not much change but fixed a misspelling and added `colnames`. As long as dataframes have *EventName* and *Zone* columns, code should create list of Zones dfs. Worked in my mock-up.

Comment: I had to simplify the data(took out columns but you can still the screenshot to compare) otherwise I have posted it at the end of the post.

Comment: So what is the problem? Posted data works perfectly in the code. See [R Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=RVKyhyRn&version=1).

Comment: again thank you very much!! This has helped me a lot!

Comment: Simply add in the subset and replace `x` with it thereafter in the `lapply` function. See updated code and R fiddle.